# How to write test cases for get image api from external url using rest assured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, rest-assured

I have a image url which will be my query parameter in the api.
Here I am fetching the image by using query parameter and respond back with `InputStreamResource`.

Can anybody help me to write the proper test cases by using rest assured. Please find the below sample code.

**Assume Sample Image URL : http://asdas.reutyure.asdas.com/AA/pet/images/cat/Test-E0173.svg**

**Image Controller**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/image")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getImage(@RequestParam("url") String url) {

        String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.length());
        byte[] byteContent = imageService.getImageData(url);
        InputStream resourceInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteContent);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream")).contentLength(byteContent.length)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(resourceInputStream));

    }
```

**Image Service**

```
public byte[] getImageData(String url) {
        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            byte[] responseEntity = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class).getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                return responseEntity;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return new byte[0];
    }
```

**ImageResourceTest**

```
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class ImageResourceTest extends BaseTest {

    private static final String IMAGE_URL_PARAMETER = "http://asdas.reutyure.asdas.com/AA/pet/images/cat/Test-E0173.svg";


    @Test
    void getImageDetails() throws Exception {
    
    // How to write proper test cases for this functionality

        given() //
                .header(authHeader()) //
                .queryParam(IMAGE_URL, IMAGE_URL_PARAMETER) //
                .when() //
                .get(contextPath + "/image") //
                .then() //
                .statusCode(200);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a [`MockRestServiceServer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) for the `RestTemplate` used in your `getImageData()` method so that it responds with a test image when an expected URL is hit. (I'd use an autowired `RestTemplate` from the application context, either default or customized.)

It'll look something like this:

```java
MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
...
mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(), 
          requestTo(new URI(IMAGE_URL)))
          .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
          .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
          .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
          .body(IOUtils.resourceToByteArray("data/test.jpg", getClass().getClassLoader()))
        );
```